# Getting error when using {{ Str::limit }} helper class in Laravel Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm building an app using Laravel 6.5, upgraded from Laravel 5.7.

I have a field that pulls text from the DB and displays the first 50 characters, using the Blade syntax:

```
...
{{ Str::limit($someValue->value, 50) }} // This worked
...
{{ Str::limit($someOtherValue->value, 50) }} // This gave error message
...
```

and when accessing the page I get

```
ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Class 'Str' not found
```

The original code uses the helper class `str_limit()` which was deprecated since Laravel 5.8.
So when I took over this project and upgraded Laravel, I updated the code to the above.

From my understanding, `Str::limit()` is a global helper class and should work without having to declare any Facade or add aliases. The fact that the above code worked partially proves it.

I implemented a working fix:

```
...
{{ Str::limit($someValue->value, 50) }} // This worked
...
{{ \Illuminate\Support\Str::limit($someOtherValue->value, 50) }} // This now works
...
```

Although I have a working fix, the ugliness of the code hurts my eyes and it drives me nuts not know **WHY** only 1 of it worked?? My linter and bracket highlighting tell me there are no missing tags. I've also copied the same code and applied in every combination, it's *just* that second `Str::limit()` which is not working.

Can anyone tell me why it's behaving this way? Thank you!

Comment: if there is an alias for `Str` in `config/app.php` then yes, you can use it as though it is in the root namespace ... there is no good reason for why you would not be able to reference the class the same way in the same file multiple times

Comment: I have added the alias to ```config/app.php``` like this ```'Str' => Illuminate\Support\Str::class,``` but it still doesn't work

Comment: @lagbox ah yes. You are absolutely right, an alias declaration was necessary. It didn't work for me initially because I didn't clear the cache. After running `php artisan view:clear` and `config:clear`. Not sure which is the cache that contributed, but it doesn't hurt to clear more cache during development. Thank you!!

Comment: if you added an alias in `config/app.php` then you would need to clear the config cache (if it was cached) ... the cache store itself doesn't need to be cleared though

Comment: Yep. It's finally working! :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use Mutator. It's a good way when you modify your data from your database. Don't make your blade file messy.

```
******* Model ********
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

public function getSomeFieldAttribute($value)
{

   return str_limit($value, 50);
}
```

**Note:** **someField** is a column that you want to limit.

Comment: @Z.Zhu If my answer is useful. Please mark it as green.

Comment: You gave a good advice, but you didn't actually answer my question

Answer (score 0):

In controller you can use code like below

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
```

then

Example :-

```
$limit_string = Str::limit('This is just an example', 5);
```

In View file if you want to use then

```
{{\Illuminate\Support\Str::limit('This is just an example',5)}}
```

you can't extend facade to blade file . if you want to use str then you have define a path and use that helper function that is limit here .

**arr** and **str** **is global function** but in **laravel 5.8 they deprecated** this functionality so if you want to use this str or arr helpers then you have to use 
Illuminate\Support\Str (str) and use Illuminate\Support\Arr (arr) to perform operation.

Comment: I'm not too sure if you can _extend_ facade into blade files. However, it's possible to create aliases for them in `config/app.php` under `aliases {}`. Clear cache to use the helpers directly without having to type the full path

Comment: yes this is another way . you can use as aliases and use in the project

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured out my problem.

```
...
if (someCondition not fulfilled) {
    {{ Str::limit($someValue->value, 50) }} // This actually didn't work but got skipped
} else {
    'Some error message' // THIS worked
...
if (someCondition fulfilled) {
    {{ Str::limit($someOtherValue->value, 50) }} // This gave error message
} else {
    'Some error message' // Skipped
...
```

The `Str` helper function only worked after declaring an alias for `Str` in `config/app.php` **and clearing the cache**: `php artisan view:clear` & `php artisan config:clear`

```
'aliases' => [

        'App' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
        'Artisan' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
        'Auth' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
        'Blade' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,

        ...

        'Str' => Illuminate\Support\Str::class
]
```

Much thanks to everyone who offered help here!